# Fetch user id from Soundcloud embed code

Tags: php, regex, soundcloud

I need to embed soundcloud url in my website , SO I am asking site users to submit the SOUNDCLOUD URL they wish to embed on their page

Is there any way I can get using PHP
 1. value of url in the iframe within src
 2. and the user id i.e. 822654

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F847884 &show_artwork=true"></iframe>
```

I tried parse_url(PHP function) but failed to fetch what I want 
If someone , can help me also know that whether every user gets an id like 847884 (in case above) or the embed code may have vanity url(like instead of 847884 can user have /bob/ or /andrew/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Script:***

```
<?php

$subject = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F847884&show_artwork=true\"></iframe>";

$pattern = '/<iframe[^>]*\ssrc="[^"]*\?url=([^&]*%2Fusers%2F(\d+)[^&]*)&/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

echo urldecode($matches[1]), "\n";
echo $matches[2], "\n";

?>
```

***Output:***

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/847884
847884
```

See it and test it [here](http://ideone.com/APoHK).